# When updating className css transition "one step behind"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a form that "slides in" the different steps as cards, e.g. when moving from step 1 to step 2 the card appears from the right, and when moving back from e.g. step 3 to step 2 the card slides in from the left.

My problem is that the direction is "one step behind", it takes two clicks in one direction for the transition to catch up.

When the prev/next buttons are clicked *handleActive()* is called:

```
const handleActive = (num, text) => {
   setDirection(text)
   setActive(num)
}
```

An example of a card div

```
<div className={active === 2 ? 'card-active' : 'card-' + direction}>
<h4>Step {active}</h4>
<input className='input' type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder='Name' />
<input className='input' type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder='Address' />
<input className='input' type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder='Phone' />
<button className='btn' type="button" onClick={() => handleActive(-1, 'from-left')}>PREV</button>
<button className='btn' type="button" onClick={() => handleActive(1, 'from-right')}>NEXT</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-from-right {
   ...
  left: 35%;
  transition: left 800ms 0ms ease-out, height 0ms 800ms, opacity 400ms 0ms ease-in;

}

.card-from-left {
   ...
  left: 25%;
  transition: left 800ms 0ms ease-out, height 0ms 800ms, opacity 400ms 0ms ease-in;
}

.card-active {
   ...
  left: 30%;
}
```

I have tried async/await in the *handleActive()* function and *useEffect*, but the only thing that works is *setTimeout* (but that's too hacky)

```
const handleActive = async (num, text) => {
await setDirection(text)
await setActive(num)
}
```

```
const handleActive = async (num, text) => {
await setDirection(text)
  setTimeout(() => {
    setActive(num)
  }, 600);
}
```

How could I pause (and modify the DOM?) to update the classNames before running *setActive()*? *Console.log* and the source code show the correct classNames, but somehow  not in time before *setActive()*...

Comment: I think using a useState hook will do what you need.  https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp Ex: const [direction, setDirection] = useState("from-left");  const [active, setActive] = useState(1);

Comment: I'm currently using Zustand from state management, but I get the same problem when using useState.

Comment: I wish I could see the state logic.  Can you use useEffect with a dependency of direction?  When direction is updated and it === x, setActive().

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough idea of using useEffect.  You could also use num as a dependency if you need. Or you could use functions.  My main point would be to put most if not all of the conditional logic inside of useEffect.  (or at least be abstracted from useEffect)

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (direction === "to-left") {
    setActive(-1)
  } else {
   setActive(1)
  }
}, [direction]);
```

Comment: The useEffect solution that I tried had the same logic. The problem is not setting the values, as both console.log and the source code show the correct values. It must have something to do with how the DOM is drawn because it works perfectly if I put a setTimeout() on setActive() (the inactive card must have the correct className applied to them before the transition starts)

Comment: @KarlNewgrove You're right.  They are both async calls.  The useEffect is designed so that instead of relying on whenever an async call finishes, it relies on when a dependency is updated.  If x is dependent on y, make them dependencies.  Don't do x, until y === "Whatevs". I could be more direct if I could see your intended logic fully.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with a "placeholder variable" - *activeSetter* (the problem with the earlier useEffect solution was that it was not triggered if the direction didn't change). Now everything happens in the right order:

- the right className is set on non-active cards
- the activeSetter holds the number of the next active card
- and changes in activeSetter triggers useEffect that sets the new active card

```
const [activeSetter, setActiveSetter] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    setActive(activeSetter)
  }, [setActive, activeSetter])
  

  const handleActive = (num, text) => {
    setDirection(text)
    setActiveSetter(num)
  }
```